# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as' error is showing

Tags: sql

I have to concatenate `First_Name` and `Last_Name` but when I do that that show incorrect syntax near `as`.

My code:

```
select COUNT(*) as Leaves,
       Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,
       First_Name,
       Last_Name as Name
from LeaveAssign
join Employee_Admission on LeaveAssign.Emp_Id= Employee_Admission.Emp_Id
WHERE D_Id='3'
group by Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,
         First_Name,
         Last_Name as Name
union
select 0 as 'Leaves',
       Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,
       First_Name,
       Last_Name as Name
from Employee_Admission
where Emp_ID not in (Select Emp_ID from LeaveAssign) and D_Id='3'
```

Comment: Not sure which sql dialect you use, but it might be the "as Name" in the "group by"!

Comment: Please identify the DBMS you are using when you ask SQL questions. And also identify tables by name — not a problem in this question, but a common mistake made by those who ask SQL questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot give alias in group by statement, hence it is giving you error. Remove `as` from the group by statement and it wont give you error. And if you want to concatenate Firstname and Lastname, do it like

```
First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name as Name
```

Answer (score 1):

`group by` does not contain `as` Keyword

Just Try this

```
select COUNT(*) as Leaves,
       Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,
       First_Name,
       Last_Name as Name
from LeaveAssign
join Employee_Admission on LeaveAssign.Emp_Id= Employee_Admission.Emp_Id
WHERE D_Id='3'
group by Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,
         First_Name,
         Last_Name
union
select 0 as 'Leaves',
       Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,
       First_Name,
       Last_Name as Name
from Employee_Admission
where Emp_ID not in
        (Select Emp_ID
         from LeaveAssign)
    and D_Id='3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select COUNT(*) as Leaves,Employee_Admission.Emp_Id,First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name as Name
from LeaveAssign join Employee_Admission on LeaveAssign.Emp_Id= Employee_Admission.Emp_Id
WHERE D_Id='3'
```